# SWI-Prolog Finding Value Of X

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have something like this in the database.

```
flight( tk1, ist, esb, 40 ).
flight( tk2, ist, mlx, 90 ).
```

And I have written a predicate called test.

```
test([S], L1):-
    findall( C, (flight( _, S, C, _ )), L1 ).
```

The output when I write `test([ist], X).` is `X = [esb, mlx].` So this is true but when I write `test(X, [esb, mlx]).` it is `false`. Why is it `false`? Should I write another predicate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you can see, [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) isn't necessarily supposed to be used with a bound last parameter, for example in SWI-Prolog, in its description we can read:

```
findall( +Template, :Goal, -Bag )
```

which indicates that `Bag` must be free when called. Some predicates sadly don't work in all possible ways!

Though, you can easily write another predicate to test that:

```
reverse_test( Cs, Ss ) :-
    findall( S, ( flight( _, S, C, _ ), member(C, Cs) ), Ss ).
```

BTW, since your relation is clearly not a bijection between `Ss` and `Cs`, you shouldn't expect the result to be reverses (`test(A, R), reverse_test(R, A2)` won't result in `A == A2`)

Answer (score 0):

I tried in SWI-Prolog, but as expected, it worked with the facts you exposed:

```
?- test(X,[esb,mlx]).
X = [_G3627].
```

If you try findall alone, you should get

```
?- findall( C, (flight( _, S, C, _ )), L1 ).
L1 = [esb, mlx].
```

Otherwise, if you for instance have another fact without ist, it fails: if I add

```
flight( tk2, xxx, mlx, 90 ).
```

then

```
?- test(X,[esb,mlx]).
false.
```